# A list of the related AplicationUsers inside of an ApplicationUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, ef-fluent-api

I Got another question today.

I Want to Relate a List of ApplicationUser into the Application User...

Something like this...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //Here are the Added Needed Values to IdentityUser to PlenaMenteTrabajando Application.

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ROLES Role { get; set; 

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Brothers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Parents{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Sons { get; set; }


    //Other Stuff
}
```

And i Don't have any Idea About what should I do with the relations...

Make another entity to store the Brothers, Parents and Sons?

Something like this...

```
public class Brother
{
    public int BrotherId{ get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Brothers{ get; set; }
}
```

Or Should i Use Fluent API do set the relations? (But i don't know how)

Or both?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this, according to the way you want to use this relationships. There are performance issues related to the different implementations.

For instance, if you have to do a lot of fast querying of the Parents, Brothers and Sons lists and little modifying of these data you could store the information redundantly, so you have a Sons/Parents table and a Brothers table, with some EF mappings for these relationships. These tables store only the primary keys of the involved people, and every time you modify one of these relationships (for instance, adding a new son) you have to update the same information in several tables.

However, if you have to do a lot of modifying of the data and not so much querying it could be better to store only the Parents table, and the list of Brothers and Sons could be inferred from there by doing queries in the code, but not by EF mappings.

An example with redundant tables: Use these mappings:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Parents).WithMany(u => u.Sons).Map( x => { x.MapRightKey("ParentId"); x.MapLeftKey("SonId"); x.ToTable("ParentsSons"); } );
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Sons).WithMany(u => u.Parents);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.Brothers).WithMany().Map(x => { x.MapRightKey("BrotherId"); x.MapLeftKey("Id"); x.ToTable("Brothers"); });
    }
```

The migration includes these tables (I added an integer `Id` property to ApplicationsUsers entity for simplicity):

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ApplicationUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                    LastName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Brothers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    BrotherId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Id, t.BrotherId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUsers", t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUsers", t => t.BrotherId)
            .Index(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.BrotherId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ParentsSons",
            c => new
                {
                    SonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ParentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.SonId, t.ParentId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUsers", t => t.SonId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUsers", t => t.ParentId)
            .Index(t => t.SonId)
            .Index(t => t.ParentId);
```

A sample method to play a little with these tables. If you debug through it you can inspect the entities and check the contents of the Parents and Sons lists. `TestContext` contains only one `DbSet` for the Users: `public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }`

```
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            var arya = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                FirstName = "Arya",
                Parents = new List<ApplicationUser>
                {
                    new ApplicationUser { FirstName = "Eddard" },
                    new ApplicationUser { FirstName = "Catelyn" }
                }
            };
            context.Users.Add(arya);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var eddard = context.Users.First(u => u.FirstName == "Eddard");
            var jon = new ApplicationUser { FirstName = "Jon" };
            eddard.Sons.Add(jon);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var eddardFromContext = context.Users.First(u => u.FirstName == "Eddard");
            var catelynFromContext = context.Users.First(u => u.FirstName == "Catelyn");
        }
    }
```

I left the Brothers list out of the example. Notice that EF does not automatically synchronize Brothers data with Parents/Sons data. So you would have to explicitly add users to the Brothers list when adding them to Parents/Sons lists. However Parents and Sons lists are automatically synchronized: if you add a user A to the Parents list of a User B and persist the data then the Parents list of user B will contain user A. That is because the mappings of Parents and Sons use the same navigation properties. That does not happen with Brothers property.